# nVidia GPU is not detected

Tags: nvidia, gpu, pci

My nVidia GPU (GTX650-DC) can't be detected by my computer(OS is Ubuntu 14.04). I've searched for related discussion([Ubuntu 14.04 couldn't detect nvidia graphic card (not even detect the model of card)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/652721/ubuntu-14-04-couldnt-detect-nvidia-graphic-card-not-even-detect-the-model-of-c)) where the nvidia GPU information can be obtained by the command "sudo lshw -C display." However, the information shown on my computer is as follows and it seems that my nvidia GPU is never detected. Have anyone run into this situation as well? Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Output of `lshw -C display *-display`  :

```
:~$ sudo lshw -C display   *-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 06
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:45 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: From the gist of a deleted answer: Did you check that the Nvidia hardware is enabled in your BIOS/UEFI settings?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the  [Nvidia](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx) site and download the correct drivers, the program will detect if you do not have the correct drivers and if not will tell you what you need to download - I had a similar experience, you don't want to force install the wrong drivers

Comment: I really find it offensive when a post is downvoted by a person who doesnt understand the answer

Comment: Indeed it's possible that the downvoter didn't understand the answer. There are two possible situations in which the Nvidia GPU is not detected: 1. It is not detected at all. 2. generic "Nvidia" device is detected, but not the device's model number. Perhaps the reviewer who downvoted was unaware of both of these possibilities and got confused.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the helpful answer by generix here: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/no-matter-which-drivers-i-install-i-cannot-boot-my-ubuntu-20-04-lts-beyond-a-black-screen/127510/9

1. switch to nvidia (again): `sudo prime-select nvidia`
2. delete `/lib/udev/rules.d/50-pm-nvidia.rules` (and delete `/lib/udev/rules.d/80-pm-nvidia.rules` too)
3. remove stray blacklist files: `sudo rm /lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf`
4. update the initrd: `sudo update-initramfs -u`
5. reboot

See also [this Nvidia Forums post](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ubuntu-19-10-with-driver-440-31-no-nvidia-graphics-adapter-found-on-rtx2060-mobile/107186/5) where generix noted:

> Ok, it’s this:
>
> `/lib/udev/rules.d/80-pm-nvidia.rules`:
>
> `ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="pci",  ATTR{vendor}=="0x10de", ATTR{class}=="0x030000", ATTR{remove}="1"`
>
> it’s removing the nvidia gpu from the bus. The rest of the file are rules to prepare for render offload.
> This looks like something changed in Ubuntu’s prime-select/nvidia-prime again, don’t really know what’s the point of doing this…

For me, `sudo prime-select nvidia` usually does the trick, but if not, manually deleting `/lib/udev/rules.d/50-pm-nvidia.rules` and `/lib/udev/rules.d/80-pm-nvidia.rules` and a reboot should do it.

Thankfully, these udev rules are going away in 20.10 (groovy) (see changelog of nvidia-prime 0.8.15), so such "Nvidia GPU disappearing" problems will soon become a thing of the past.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but in case it helps someone, for me the command

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA'
```

did not show my nvidia GPU. Modifying the command to this *did* show it:

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
```

giving the following output:

```
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 02)
        Subsystem: Dell UHD Graphics
        Kernel driver in use: i915
--
0000:02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX250] (rev ff)
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
0000:03:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
```

It seems it is set as `3D controller`, rather than `VGA compatible controller`.