# Graphics card is not being utilized at all and Blender 2.8 wont detect it

Tags: gpu, blender, gpu-driver, additional-drivers

soo its kind of 2 problems, 1 is that my graphics device is not being shown as my gpu (GTX 1050 Mobile) but like this
[idk what this is but this is my current graphics device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfoz6.png)
. my second problem kinda relates to the first, is that in Blender 2.8 is not detecting any CUDA gpus. when i installed ubuntu, the Blender viewport was nice and smooth, but i tried installing lots of drivers to try and get it to show for cycles rendering, buuuut i made it worse and now lags really bad even with the default cube.

im new on ubuntu so umm yea.. ive also been trying to fix this problem for a week now and ive searched everywhere, watched multiple tutorials, read lots of guides, reinstalled drivers, etc plz help >n<

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04 couldn't detect nvidia graphic card (not even detect the model of card)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/652721/ubuntu-14-04-couldnt-detect-nvidia-graphic-card-not-even-detect-the-model-of-c)

Answer (score 0):

The llvmpipe is a software opengl renderer from the [mesa project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesa_(computer_graphics)#Software_renderer) which is open source.

Nvidia provides binary drivers for its video cards, you need these [official drivers](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in-linux) to get access to CUDA in blender. You may also need the [CUDA toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) if the CUDA support needs recompiling.