# Unable to detect the right graphics driver

Tags: 16.04, drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

I have done a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS recently on an HP laptop with AMD graphics card, however I have noticed occasional screen flickering and Ubuntu freezing after suspend.

I tried looking into the graphics driver in use and found that currently Ubuntu uses:

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
```

Intel Graphics, I want to switch to AMD however I don't know the details of the graphics card and needed a guide as to how I can Install the driver and get Ubuntu to recognise it.

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
== cpu-microcode.py ==
driver   : intel-microcode - distro non-free
```

It does not recommend any other drivers.

**Edit: 1**

This [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/523528/why-does-ubuntu-14-04-not-recognize-nvidia-geforce-310m-hardware) was helpful in detecting AMD graphics, how do I now switch to AMD graphics card?

```
lspci -nn | grep '\[03'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics [8086:1616] (rev 09)
0a:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265] [1002:6900] (rev ff)
```

Comment: problem is Ubuntu is not able to detect AMD so I am not able to obtain the graphic card details to enable me to install the driver from [here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download)

Comment: The AMD graphics driver is built-in in Ubuntu 16.04 so you don't need to download anything, and as you noted your problem is that Ubuntu is not able to detect the AMD graphics card.